# How to build/create mongoid multi-level embedded document upon creation of the root while respecting all natural callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, mongoid

Let's say I have a structure of models like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :personal_data
  embeds_one :professional_data

  ...
end

class PersonalData
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :family_data

  field :stuff, :type => String

  ...
end

class ProfessionalData
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :stuff, :type => String

  ...
end
```

So simply put a user would have a tree of data that would look like this:

```
User -> PersonalData -> FamilyData
     -> ProfessionalData
```

As you may have noticed, each of my models uses Mongoid:Timestamps as I want to know when each sub part of the user gets modified.

Now where it gets tricky, is that I want upon creating a new User, that it automatically gets all its embedded model created with it while using the proper callbacks to set the Timestamps.

Ideally I would like to avoid doing multiple writes to the DB, but I haven't found an elegant way of doing this so far.

For the moment I have this in my User model:

```
after_create :create_personal_data
after_create :create_professional_data
```

And in PersonalData model:

```
after_create :create_family_data
```

However the results are not what I am expecting, it works great for the ProfessionalData model, where it gets created and the TimeStamps callback works, :created_at and :updated_at are set properly.
However for the PersonalData model, it does not work properly:
- the embedded model gets created
- but the callback are not called properly, and TimeStamps are not set
- the embedded FamilyData does not get created un PersonalData

I am using Mongoid 2.4.12 with Rails 3.2

Thx.

Alex

Comment: Ok, well my bad, it works fine, I had a validation issue on the PersonalData model. However this raises an additional issue in the sense of what I would have wanted in that case if not to have the user persisted at all rather than partially...

Comment: And there is also the multi write issue of course